# ROS C++: nh.subscribe vs message_filters::Subscriber<> , nh.subscribe works well but message_filters::Subscriber<> does not work

Tags: c++, ros, slam

I'm tring to learn ROS topic, but I met a problem that really confused me.

Here is the origin code. It works well, I can receive the image and pass it to CamImgcb.

```
mSubCam = mNh.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Image>(TopicNameCamSub,10,boost::bind(&ClientHandler::CamImgCb,this,_1));
```

But when I change it to this code below, CamImgcb can not receive anything, the whole program is stuck to wait for the image to come.

```
message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image> rgb_sub(mNh, TopicNameCamSub, 10);
rgb_sub.registerCallback(boost::bind(&ClientHandler::CamImgCb,this,_1));
```

My question is that aren't those two codes means the exact same thing? Why is there a difference between them? I just can't figure it out.

Does anyone know what is the problem? Please help me and thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a while back and found the solution [here](https://github.com/ros2/message_filters/issues/20#issuecomment-522496584).

Try changing:

```
rgb_sub.registerCallback(boost::bind(&ClientHandler::CamImgCb,this,_1));
```

To:

```
rgb_sub.registerCallback(&ClientHandler::CamImgCb, this);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, the problem is about class member, you can check the link below.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it , the solution is here!

https://answers.ros.org/question/406915/nhsubscribe-works-but-message_filterssubscriber-not/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).